# Pandas dataframe - column transpose

Tags: python, pandas

given the dataframe

```
user month      valueX   valueY
--------------------------------
884  2013-01    1        5
889  2013-02    0        15
884  2013-02    7        29
889  2013-01    9        38
```

how can I get to this one:

```
user |2013-01-valueX |2013-02-valueX  |2013-01-valueY  |2013-02-valueY
--------------------------------------------------------------------
884  |1              |7               |5               |19
889  |9              |0               |38              |15
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use unstack

```
df1 = df.set_index(['user', 'month'])[['valueX', 'valueY']].unstack()
df1.columns = df1.columns.swaplevel().map('-'.join)
df1 = df1.reset_index()

    user    2013-01-valueX  2013-02-valueX  2013-01-valueY  2013-02-valueY
0   884     1               7               5               29
1   889     9               0               38              15
```

Edit: As @Zero suggested, you can combine multi-index columns without using swaplevel() like this,

```
df.columns = df1.columns.map('{0[1]}-{0[0]}'.format)
```

Comment: `df1.columns.map(lambda x: '{1}-{0}'.format(*x))` wouldn't need `swaplevel`

Comment: @Zero, yeah. Adding it to the answer. Thank you:)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the pivot function:

```
df2 = df.pivot(index='user', columns='month')
```

which groups rows according to 'user' and groups columns according to 'month'.

The result is:

```
     valueX          valueY        
month 2013-01 2013-02 2013-01 2013-02
user                                 
884         1       7       5      29
889         9       0      38      15
```

Note: The columns are now a multilevel index, for example to get valueX for user 889 on 2013-01 you need to do: `df2.loc[889, ('valueX', '2013-01')]`, or for all dates: `df2.loc[889, ('valueX', slice(None))]`